# When does TFVC show anything about conflicts when 2 branches are merged?

Tags: merge, tfvc

I merged my Main branch onto my Dev branch so that my Dev branch is upto date with my Main branch.

1. I performed merge.
2. It showed pending changes.

When will it ever show anything about CONFLICTS?

Comment: If there are none and all content was able to merge without conflicts, the merge has been performed.

Comment: But I have conflicting content and still no conflicts are shown.

Comment: Then there may be a previous merge ticket that has already resolved that conflict. TFVC does bookkeeping under the hood on the server. It can be very confusing.

Comment: You can force a merge if you have to. Use the commandline `tf merge /recursive /force $/project/dev $project/main`